# Removing Xterm terminal

Tags: xterm

I seem to have installed something that replaced the default terminal with xterm. How do I get rid of it and bring the default terminal back?

Comment: What did you install?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) "Some error" can be quite easily fixed by doing "something".
So unless you tell us what you did, it's a bit hard for us to help you reverse it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Ubuntu Software Center` search for `gnome-terminal`.Then Install it.
Type in the `Dash`  `gnome-terminal`.That's it.

Answer (score 3):

The default is `gnome-terminal`, but the default may have been overwritten with `xterm`. The command that lets you choose is `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` .